# Magento 2 pub/media/catalog folder size too big

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, media, media-images

I have magento2 setup with `~6000 products` and the size of the `pub/media/catelog` folder was **23GB**,

Now suddenly it has increased to **~51GB** and the server storage is started showing 100%.

I am not sure that is intended behaviour or do I need to increase the storage of the server?

Comment: Magento caches all images in various sizes, depending on your theme. This could mean that if you have 10 different image sizes defined in your theme, it does create 10x6000 variants of the image. So it looks like intended behavior to me.

Comment: Thanks Giel, I do use a third party theme. Where do I find  all the image sizes that are defined by the theme?

Comment: You can find all the available theme specific image sizes in the theme folder inside etc/view.xml

Comment: You can also use an NFS or CDN to store images. And you can try to clear catalog image cache to see if there is some old images not used.

Comment: Theme has more than 10 definitions for different sizes, I had to increase server space. Thanks @FranckGarnier

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento makes 3 copies of your files, one for the thumbnail, one for small, and the Normal sized one.  if you are using cache this means per 1 product you could have up 9 copies, per single image added per product.

I ran an image optimizer to try and reduce my files sizes, be cautious as mass jpg optimizers don't always reduce the files and can create colour table errors, as I experienced recently with some jpg's that where 5000x3000px, 10mb per file, it reduced them by 12% but the colours where all messed up.

Follow the Magento guidelines for image sizes dimensions, yes will take a long time to produce, for the 3 size types, but if you create for all 3, the thumbnail and the small should only be a few kb each where as you main image can be 500kb avg. and vastly reduce your taken hdd space.