# Magento 2 pub/media/catalog/product/n/o folder size too big

Tags: error

[Magento ver. 2.1.2 BUG "multiple image generation on product copy](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9466#issuecomment-305824682)

Magento 2.1.2 pub/media/catalog/product/n/o 12 GB folder size too big

Now currently 1900 products in my store and issue is duplicate images generated.

[this link not working for me](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146165/magento-2-pub-media-catalog-folder-size-too-big)

Advance thanks for help

Comment: We need a little more information here. Is there an (automated) import running that imports images?

Comment: how to check it this type of script working or not @MarcodeVries